# Django. How to make comments? - The simplest example. CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, django, comments, foreign-key-relationship, django-csrf

I want to create a very simple website, where everyone can post a poem, and everyone can comment other poems. So: one poem on the template, and lots of comments. I know, that there is Django-disqus - framework using to comment, but I'm new in Django so I want to learn step by step and Django-disqus is too dificult for me at the time.
I'm trying do it this way, just for a training:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Poem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    like = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    nick = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    poem = models.ForeignKey(Poem, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from poems.models import Poem, Comment

def comment(request, poem_id):
    if poem_id:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            text_of_comment = request.POST.get('text_of_comment')
            nick = request.POST.get('nick')
            comment = Comment.objects.create(title = title, text = text_of_comment, nick = nick, poem = Poem.objects.get(id=poem_id))
            comment.save()
            comments = Poem.objects.get(id = poem_id)
            all_comments = comments.comment_set.all()
            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['all_comments'] = all_comments
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/poems/get/%s' % poem_id, args)
        else:
            comments = Poem.objects.get(id = poem_id)
            all_comments = comments.comment_set.all()
            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['all_comments'] = all_comments
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/poems/get/%s' % poem_id, args)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^comment/(?P<poem_id>\d+)/$', 'poems.views.comment')
```

poems.html:

```
{%  extends "base.html"  %}


{%  block sidebar  %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{%  url 'poems.views.poems'  %}">Poems</a></li>
        </ul>
{%  endblock  %}

{%  block content  %}


<h2>{{  poem.title  }}</h2>
<p>{{  poem.text  }}</p>
<p>{{  poem.like  }} person likes this poem.</p>

<a href="/poems/like/{{  poem.id  }}" class="btn btn-success btn-large active"><i class="icon-white icon-heart"></i> Like it!</a>





<form method="post" action="/poems/comment/{{  poem.id  }}/">{% csrf_token %}

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="title" id="title"></p>
    <label for="text">Comment</label>
    <p><textarea id="text" name="text_of_comment" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea></p>
    <label for="nick">Nick</label>
    <p><input id="nick" name="nick" type="text"></p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" value="OK"/>

</form>
{%  for comment in all_comments  %}
    <h5>{{  comment.title  }}</h5>
    <p>{{  comment.text  }}</p>
    <p>{{  comment.nick  }}</p>
{%  endfor  %}

{%  endblock  %}
```

First of all: When I runserver and post a comment, it returns:

Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

I don't understand why, cause all of my other functions and templates are build the same way and works correctly. 
What I'm doing wrong?

Second: Is my way of using ForeignKey() in the comment() function correct? Is that good way to create comments under a poem? How do you guys solve that problem?

Thanx for anwsers :)

Comment: Did you remember to import the CSRF? `from django.core.context_processors import csrf`

Comment: just a suggestion use NoSQL instead of RDBMS for storing comments and poems its perfect for this kind of scenarios.

Comment: @Deepend Yes, I remember that.

Comment: @Sar009 I know that RDBMS is not effective in some scenarios, but that project just for practice. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete your all cookies to solve your CSRF problem (I had the same in the past and works after delete my cookies)

About your models is ok if you don't have nested comments.

You didn't ask but I will give you an advice for your code, use reverse for URL's, because someday if you change something, you will have to fix everywhere...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: +1 about usage of reverse for URL!
I also advise you to use [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) , you code will be much more nicer as well!

Comment: @Lara I deleted cookies. It returns the same Error, but with different reason: Reason given for failure: CSRF cookie not set.
previously: CSRF token missing or incorrect. I don't know what does it mean.. Thank you for advice about usage of reverse URL's, I will probably face URL's problems soon.

Comment: @trnsnt Thanx, Form is my next lesson ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

The comment() function redirect to another function:

```
    `return HttpResponseRedirect('/poems/get/%s' % poem_id, args)`
```

so function under that url: `'/poems/get/%s' % poem_id`

should contain CSRF token.

Should look like this:

`def poem(request, poem_id = 1):
    args = {}
    poem = Poem.objects.get(id = poem_id)
    args['poem'] = poem
    all_comments = poem.comment_set.all()
    args['all_comments'] = all_comments
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('poems/poem.html', args)`

now it works without Forbidden (403) :)